# How to make a http web asyncGET request

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make a get request. Here is the code I tested:

```
public string Get(string uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip 
                                     | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

but the problem is it will freeze GUI and  I found this code:

```
public async Task<string> GetAsync(string uri)
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
   request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip 
                                   | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

   using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
   using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
   using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
       return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
   }
}
```

but I am not good at multitasking.

anyhelp how to use this function? 
tnx

Comment: Your above code looks alright to me. Function signature has included `async` and you have got 2 await included in function body. Are you facing any problem? I dont see scope of `Tasks.Parallel` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. All you need to do is to call `GetAsync` function with `await` and you will get the desired result.

Please do not forget to include `async` in the signature of calling function. Support you have `GetText` from where you want to use `GetAsync` then code snippet would be:

```
private async void GetText()
{
    string str = await GetAsync(url);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want to do, but you can try to remove the usings because you only need to add the usings in the imports section and try to use your method more like this:

public class HttpHandler
        {

```
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


        public async Task<string> Get(string apiURL)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiURL);
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: tnx i will try this ,
i want to make a get request of a urls which are in a list box but because they are a lots of data and takes time to finish loop the ui is not responsible i searched and found that code that similar to work on another threat (task) but i do not know how to call it and use this